# Should we training RNNs with sliding window on non-stationary data?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, stationarity

For a stationary time series, I know that training with a sliding time-window (i.e. train on $t=1,\ldots,100$ and then test on $t=101$, then train on $t=2,\ldots,t=101$ and test on $t=102$ and so on.) is not necessary since the RNN is able to pick up dependencies over previous time steps in the data. But what about the case when the data is non-stationary? It would make sense to me that a sliding window approach might not even produce better results, but in fact should be the correct way to train such a given data set.

I've found some possibly related work done by in a paper titled 'Time series forecasting for nonlinear and non-stationary processes' (Cheng et al., 2015) but this is unfortunately pay-walled. So my question is, is using a sliding window the proper way to properly train an RNN on non-stationary data? Otherwise, how should we go about training the RNN given non-stationary data?